# [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app - Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

*Not a duplicate: already check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053309/vue-warn-cannot-find-element-empty-container-is-rendered) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484431/vue-warn-cannot-find-element); didn't get any clue. Some of similar ones are related to Laravel.*

Can't figure out what was changed in my project, making `[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app` appear.

The structure:

**index.html**: hosts the `<div id="app">`:

```
[HEADER]

<div id="app" v-cloak></div>

[FOOTER]
```

**main.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Users from './Users.vue';
import App from './App.vue';             // (1)
import Home from './Home.vue';           // (2)
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';      // (3)

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {path: '/users', component: Users},
  {path: '/', component: Home}
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

EDIT: when changed the last block to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
  })
})
```

it didn't help either.

**App.vue**:

```
<template>
  <router-view>
</router-view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      message: "Test message"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Home.vue**:

```
<template>
    [contents]
    [router-links]
</template>

<script>
    [data]
    [methods]
</script>
```

Whenever I get to the index page, the Vue warn gets displayed. One of attached questions I checked suggested that the DOM element is not ready when scripts are running. Already tried to switch order of imports in `main.js` (App, Home and VueRouter, as marked in comments), but with no success.

Any idea where to look for solution?

Comment: Your `script` tag with your spa should be right under #app div tag. Are you sure that it works well with your template engine?

Comment: You can also use the `defer` attribute in the script tag or the `window.addEventListener("load", <your function>);` method

Comment: @Bellian: Used jQuery ready function for this (see edited part), but with no success.

Comment: yan you also post where and how you include the main.js?

Comment: @Bellian: It is processed by webpack, link is at the end of <body> tag.

Comment: Are you using a regular browser or a environment like nwjs?

Comment: @Bellian: A regular browser, Chromium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, found the bug:

**index.html**:

```
(...)
      </footer>
   <script src="../dist/build.js"></script>
</body>
```

The script over there is located in a *build* directory. However, webpack generates its own script file on the fly and runs the application from it. The script mentioned above in the code was simply overwriting values correctly loaded before. Deleting the `../dist/` directory and commenting the script line out brought everything back to normal.